# how to solve the 'Failed to load resource: cannot parse response' on safari

Tags: reactjs, webpack, safari, webpack-dev-server

I have a web app built in React and web pack. The problem is When I make any request to api on Safari, the error 'Failed to load resource: cannot parse response' appears. It works fine on Chrome or Firefox.

Is there any way to solve it by configure web pack ?

I did try to do some research and try webpack-dev-server --https but still not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.